# How to prevent images from flickering when slidingDown() over each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm just starting to use html (and jQuery) and can't figure out the following problem.

I'm trying to make some sort of photo slider gallery. On the left, on top of each other, there are some categories, and every 3-4 seconds, the top categorie slides to the right (and expanding its width) and drops down. On the dropdown it opens an image, of the specific categorie. To make the loop contineous I need two divs, sliding down over each other, see the following code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Galerij</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/CSS_Galerij.css">
<script src="Javascripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
var But = new Array(
'#But1','#But2','#But3','#But4','#But5','#But6','#But7');
var But_Pos = new Array(
'0px','68px','136px','204px','272px','340px','408px');
var Images = new Array(
"Images/Stoel/Stoel_Alpha_1.jpg",
"Images/Gestoffeerde_Stoel/Gestoffeerde_Stoel_Kokonstoel_1.jpg",
"Images/Schommelstoel/Schommelstoel_Delta_1.jpg",
"Images/Tuinbank/Tuinbank_Beta_1.jpg",
"Images/Kast/Kast_Modulekast_1.jpg",
"Images/Salontafel/Salontafel_Klassiek_1.jpg",
"Images/Overig/Overig_Compartimentendoos_1.jpg");

var Num_But = 7;
var Track_Img = -1;
var Track_Large_Img = 0;
var speed = 1000;
var speed2 = 940;
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#imgl1').attr('src',Images[0]);
$(But[0]).animate({left:'233px',width:'475'},speed).animate({top:'612px'},speed,Set    _But_Array);
for (var i=1;i<7;i++) {
    $(But[i]).delay(speed).animate({top:But_Pos[i-1]},speed)
}
$('#divimg1').delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
Track_Large_Img++;


}); 

function Set_But_Array() {
    var temp = But[0];
    for (var i=1;i<Num_But;i++) {
        But[i-1]=But[i];
    }
    But[(Num_But-1)] = temp;    
    Loop();
}
function Loop() {
if (Track_Img == -1) {

    $('.img2').css('z-index','101');
    $('.img1').css('z-index','99');
    $('#imgl2').attr('src',Images[Track_Large_Img]);
    $('#divimg2').delay(4*speed).slideDown(speed2);
    $('#divimg1').delay(5*speed).slideUp(10);
}
else if (Track_Img == 1) {

    $('.img1').css('z-index','100');
    $('.img2').css('z-index','99');
    $('#imgl1').attr('src',Images[Track_Large_Img]);
    $('#divimg1').delay(4*speed).slideDown(speed2);
    $('#divimg2').delay(5*speed).slideUp(10);
}
$(But[0]).delay(3*speed).animate({left:'233px',width:'475'},speed).animate({top:'61    2px'},speed);
$(But[6]).delay(3*speed).animate({left:'0',width:'225'},speed).animate({top:But_Pos    [5]},speed,Set_But_Array);
for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
    $(But[i]).delay(4*speed).animate({top:But_Pos[i-1]},speed)
}
Track_Img = (-1) * Track_Img;
Track_Large_Img++;
if (Track_Large_Img > (Num_But-1)) {
    Track_Large_Img = 0;
}
}

</script>


</head>

<body>

<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%">

<!--- Hoofd Logo --->
<div class="divhoofdlogo">
<a href="Main_Page.html"><img class="hoofdlogo" src="Images/Logo.png"></a>
</div>
<!--- Einde Hoofd Logo --->

<div style="position:absolute;width:723px;height:708px;top:25%;left:50%;margin-left:-361.5px;">
<div class="divbutton" id="But1" style="top:0px;"><a class="buttons" href="Stoelen.html?0,0">Stoelen</a></div>
<div class="divbutton" id="But2" style="top:68px;"><a class="buttons" href="Gestoffeerde_Stoelen.html?0,0">Gestoffeerde Stoelen</a></div>
<div class="divbutton" id="But3" style="top:136px;"><a class="buttons" href="Schommelstoelen.html?0,0">Schommelstoelen</a></div>
<div class="divbutton" id="But4" style="top:204px;"><a class="buttons" href="Tuinbanken.html?0,0">Tuinbanken</a></div>
<div class="divbutton" id="But5" style="top:273px;"><a class="buttons" href="Kasten.html?0,0">Kasten</a></div>
<div class="divbutton" id="But6" style="top:340px;"><a class="buttons" href="Salontafels.html?0,0"></a>Salontafels</div>
<div class="divbutton" id="But7" style="top:408px;"><a class="buttons" href="Overig.html?0,0">Overig</a></div>
<div class="img1" id="divimg1"><img class="img1" id="imgl1" src="Images/Salontafel/Salontafel_Combi_1.jpg"></div>
<div class="img2" id="divimg2"><img class="img2" id="imgl2" src="Images/Stoel/Stoel_Alpha_1.jpg"></div>

</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.divbutton {
position:absolute;
vertical-align:middle;
width:225px;
height:60px;
left:0px;
border:solid 2px #CCC;
text-align:center;
background-image:url(../Images/Wood.jpg);
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:60px;
z-index:102;
}

.divhoofdlogo  {

  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-259px;
  width:518px;
  height:140px;
}

img.hoofdlogo  {
  width:518px;
  height:140px;
}

a.buttons {
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}

#divimg1 {
position:absolute;
width:456,75px;
height:600px;
left:248.25px;
display:none;
z-index:100;
}

#divimg2 {
position:absolute;
width:456,75px;
height:600px;
left:248.25px;
display:none;
z-index:99;
}

#imgl1 {
width:456,75px;
height:600px;
}

#imgl2 {
width:456,75px;
height:600px;
}
```

At first site it works. However, sometimes the images flicker, and the upper half of the image which is shown at that time seems to dissapear and the image in the other div (loaded with the next image) is shown. I read somewhere that it can be because of different things happening at the same time, so i've tried to include some delays but couldn't find the solution. Hope someone can help me with this..

Comment: Anybody wanting a working sample JSBin link: http://jsbin.com/AbosELu/1/edit?html,css,js,output , it works but you can still see the flickering.

Comment: I don't see a flicker. Maybe it depends on the speed of the computer you're viewing it on? Also, the pictures don't match the text on the buttons.

Comment: I will try to post a link with a sample including the actual pictures this afternoon, maybe you can see the flickering then as well..

Comment: Here is the link to the sample with the correct images: http://bwbv.marklalieu.nl/Galerij.html . However now i seem to have a problem with the background image of the buttons, but that shouldn't be difficult to fix..

Answer (score 1):

I think I discovered the problem with the code, and fixed it. Please let me know if you think it might have been the problem indeed, and the answer is correct..

If you look at the times of the different animations, you can see that one loop takes:

```
5*speed
```

The animation slides down two pictures/two div's over each other. But to slide something down several times, you must slide it up in between. I thought to do this very quickly behind the scenes, when the z-index of the div/image was below that of the div/image that is shown at that moment. So, when one image is fully slid down, the other one behind that image slides back up very quickly. However, this is after the:

```
5*speed
```

In the code:

```
$('#divimg1').delay(5*speed).slideUp(10);
```

So the

```
slideUp(10);
```

part is actually happening in the new loop. That loop starts by reversing the z-indexes.. thus putting the image which is sliding up in 0.01 s on the front. That is why it looks like only the top half of the image is flickering. I guess that's the problem.

The solution is quite simple i think.. just delay the z-index change till after the slideUp:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.img2').css('z-index','101');
    $('.img1').css('z-index','99');
}, 150);
```

This solution seems to work: It didn't flicker for 3-4 rounds!
Thanks for the responses to my question!